# Twilio Receive Fax, Body is Empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twilio

I'm trying to get started with Twilio's Programmable Fax API and I have completed their getting started guide. However, when I receive the fax, I log the request body to the console. However, the body is just an empty object. 
I'm not sure what is going wrong.

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

// Parse any incoming POST parameters
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: false }));

// Define a handler for when the fax is initially sent
app.post('/fax/sent', (req, res) => {
  // Let's manually build some TwiML. We can choose to receive the
  // fax with <Receive>, or reject with <Reject>.
  console.log(req.body);

  const twiml = `
  <Response>
    <Receive action="/fax/received" mediaType="application/pdf" storeMedia="true"/>
  </Response>
  `;

  // Send Fax twiml response
  res.type('text/xml');
  res.send(twiml);
});

// Define a handler for when the fax is finished sending to us - if successful,
// We will have a URL to the contents of the fax at this point
app.post('/fax/received', (req, res) => {
  // log the URL of the PDF received in the fax
  console.log(req.body);    
  // Respond with empty 200/OK to Twilio
  res.status(200);
  res.send(req.body);
});

// Start the web server
http.createServer(app).listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Express server listening on port 3000');
});
```

And here is what I get back in the console. You can see the empty object that is logged...

```
Express server listening on port 3000
{}
```

UPDATE:
I changed the body parser middleware to use urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
And I get the object but I don't see a media url...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With later versions of [Express, 4.16.0 - Release date: 2017-09-28](https://expressjs.com/en/changelog/4x.html), you don't need to require body-parser.

```
// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Answer (score 0):

BodyParser has updated since their documentation was written. You need to do

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```